# NFS: Hot Pursuit friends from different platforms

Tags: need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

I'm looking at getting NFS: Hot Pursuit, but would like to know if the Autolog feature recognizes friends from different platforms, or is it localized to the platform that you purchase the game on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked EA Support at http://support.ea.com/app/ask and they said:

> Miguel: As the servers are platform specific,
>   you will be able to make friends who
>   are playing the game on the same platform. So, there is no cross-platform support for Hot Pursuit.

Comment: Well that's fairly ordinary...

Comment: Well, they'd have to get Sony and Microsoft to work together and share networking information and whatever, which doesn't seem likely...